# Checking file exists or not in android is not working

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android app. I am still learning android. But I am having a problem with checking file in download folder exists or not. It is always returning false. But the file actually exists.

This is the function to check file exists or not in CommonHelper class

```
    public static boolean fileExists(String path)
    {
        File file = new File(path);
        if(file.exists())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is how I am checking files in built in download folder

```
   if(CommonHelper.fileExists(String.valueOf(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/"+cursor.getString(1)))
   {
         //do other stuffs here
   }
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What is the outcome of `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/"+cursor.getString(1)`? Is it really the full path to your file? Maybe you are missing the file extension?

Comment: It is returning something like this  Download/5391454763980398.mp3 and file exists actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you are not getting the full path.

Try getting the path with `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`

```
public static boolean fileExists(File path, String filename){
        return new File(path, filename).exists();
}
```

And then call:

```
CommonHelper.fileExists(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), cursor.getString(1));
```

**EDIT**: Please note, `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` can also be something else, like `getExternalStorageDirectory()` depending, on where you actually stored your file.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if(CommonHelper.fileExists(new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),cursor.getString(1)))
{
     //do other stuffs here
}
```

and

```
 public static boolean fileExists(File directory, String fileName)
{
    File file = new File(directory,fileName);
    if(file.exists())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hay cannot pass Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS as first argument. I think it is not File type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    File file = getContext().getFileStreamPath(file_name);       
   if(file.exists()){

    FileInputStream fileIn= new FileInputStream(file);
     ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the file name to the path when creating the file... Please try as below..

```
File file = new File(storagePath + "/" + fileName);
if (file.exists()) {
   return true;
}
else
{
 return false;
}
```

Comment: With my code,
It is returning something like this Download/5391454763980398.mp3 and file exists actually.

Answer (score -1):

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/filename");

if(file.exists){
    return true;
}else{
return false;
}
```